# Поиск строки из текста по подстроке

Tags: python, строки

Здравствуйте.
Допустим существует текст в текстовой переменной STR:

```
1212
FDFER5678

golFINDME1244fwfw
fewf
3434
```

Требуется по подстроке "FINDME", из текста найти ее местоположение в тексте и вырезать всю строку, в которой она содержится, от \n до \n.

Требуемый результат работы кода будет "golFINDME1244fwfw".

Желательно использовать python 2.

Comment: Что вы попытались сделать и почему у вас не получилось?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
STR = """1212
FDFER5678

golFINDME1244fwfw
fewf
3434"""

lst = STR.split('\n')
for line in lst:
    if "FINDME" in line:
        print line
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

Findall = """1212
FDFER5678

golFINDME1244fwfw
fewf
3434"""
mother = Findall.split()
for word in mother:
    if re.search('FINDME', word):
        print (word)
```

Comment: в вопросе просят *"от \n до \n."* найти, а не от пробела до пробела.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы найти первую строчку, содержащую заданную подстроку:

```
>>> import re    
>>> re.search(r'^.*FINDME.*$', STR, re.MULTILINE).group()
'golFINDME1244fwfw'
```

Чтобы найти все такие строки:

```
>>> re.findall('^.*FINDME.*$', STR, re.MULTILINE)
['golFINDME1244fwfw']
```